# How to Create Arrays of Objects With A Common Prop Value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of objects like:

```
flattenedObjects = [
  {name: 'Bill', city: 1},
  {name: 'Guillermo', city: 1},
  {name: 'Wilhem', city: 1},
  {name: 'William', city: 1},
  {name: 'Nick', city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicolas', city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicholas', city: 2},
  {name: 'Rick', city: 3}
]
```

I want to create individual arrays of objects grouped by "city". In the code, I will also deconstruct each object so that the final output will be:

```
boston = ['Bill', 'Guillermo', 'Wilhelm', 'William']
miami = ['Nick', 'Nickolas', 'Nicholas']
london = ['Rick']
```

I am having difficulties creating the grouped array of objects.

I can do it with one single object, as such:

```
let boston = flattenedObjects.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.city == 1;
});
```

What I was thinking of doing was to take a iterate through an object and filtering dynamically, like so:

```
let cities = {
  boston: 1,
  miami: 2,
  london: 3
}
```

And then trying something like:

```
let newObj = flattenedObjects.filter(function (x) {
  let obj = {};
  Object.entries(cities).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    obj["name"] = `${key}`;
    obj["city"] = x.city == `${value}`;
    return obj;
  });
});
```

This isn't consoling what is expected. It's just an array of objects very similar to the "obj" up above.

Comment: The `flattenedObjects` isn't an array. Did you mean, `flattenedObjects = [ {name: 'Bill', city: 1}, /* ... */ ]`?

Comment: `flattenedObjects` is an object, so you can't call array methods on it. The `filter` function also isn't returning true/false for what values should be returned in any resultant array. In your data structure the city is a number, but you expect it to be grouped into cities by name, is there some other relevant code you've not shared?

Comment: @DrewReese [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback accepts truthy/falsey values as the return type (so, any value), though it is more semantically correct to return a boolean.

Comment: Yes, sorry "flattenedObjects" is an array and I can filter through it (as demonstrated later in the example). It was a spelling mistake.

Comment: @j1mbl3s I understand how array filtering works, OP's code is returning undefined for each element since there is an implicit void return.

Comment: @DrewReese I think that's a different issue than "The `filter` function also isn't returning true/false ...". `undefined` coerces to `false` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let flattenedObjects = [
  {name: 'Bill',city: 1},
  {name: 'Guillermo',city: 1},
  {name: 'Wilhem',city: 1},
  {name: 'William',city: 1},
  {name: 'Nick',city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicolas',city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicholas',city: 2},
  {name: 'Rick',city: 3}
];

let cities = {
  boston: 1,
  miami: 2,
  london: 3
}

let data = {}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(cities)) {
  data[key] = flattenedObjects.filter(p => p.city === value).map(e => e.name);
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a reverse map of city code to city name, `O(1)` constant time lookups.
2. Reduce the `flattenedObjects` array into an object using the city name as a key and generate an array fo the names, `O(n)` linear access.

```js
const flattenedObjects = [
  { name: "Bill", city: 1 },
  { name: "Guillermo", city: 1 },
  { name: "Wilhem", city: 1 },
  { name: "William", city: 1 },
  { name: "Nick", city: 2 },
  { name: "Nicolas", city: 2 },
  { name: "Nicholas", city: 2 },
  { name: "Rick", city: 3 }
];

const cities = {
  boston: 1,
  miami: 2,
  london: 3
};

const citiesByCode = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(cities).map(([city, code]) => [code, city])
);

const groupedResult = flattenedObjects.reduce((groups, current) => {
  const cityCode = citiesByCode[current.city];
  if (!groups[cityCode]) groups[cityCode] = [];
  groups[cityCode].push(current.name);
  return groups;
}, {});

console.log(groupedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) statement to reduce the `flattenedObjects` array into a single object in the format that you want.

```js
const flattenedObjects = [
  {name: 'Bill', city: 1},
  {name: 'Guillermo', city: 1},
  {name: 'Wilhem', city: 1},
  {name: 'William', city: 1},
  {name: 'Nick', city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicolas', city: 2},
  {name: 'Nicholas', city: 2},
  {name: 'Rick', city: 3},
];
// the keys are the city number rather than city name
const cities = {
  1: 'boston',
  2: 'miami',
  3: 'london',
};

const obj = flattenedObjects.reduce((o, flattenedObject) => {
  const cityName = cities[flattenedObject.city];
  if (o[cityName] === undefined) {
    o[cityName] = [];
  }
  o[cityName].push(flattenedObject.name);
  return o;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```